# Delete object with a protected destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, protected

I am fairly new to C++ memory management. I read [Should every class have a virtual destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353817/should-every-class-have-a-virtual-destructor) and found this answer:

> Every abstract class should either have a
>
> - protected destructor or
> - virtual destructor
>
> If you've got a public non-virtual destructor, that's no good, since it allows users to delete through that pointer a derived object. Since as we all know, that's undefined behavior.
>
> For a class not intended to delete through a pointer to it, there is no reason whatsoever to have a virtual destructor. It would not only waste resources, but more importantly it would give users a wrong hint. Just think about what crappy sense it would make to give std::iterator a virtual destructor.

So I have a protected destructor now (I am not deriving from the class).

In another class though I have a pointer to this object. In my constructor I make give the pointer a "new" object of that class, in my destrcutor I would like to destroy it.

How do I do that? If the destructor is not protected I get a seg fault (which I don't entirely understand but I realise is bad programming anyway). If the destructor is protected I don't know how to delete the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the term "abstract" in the block above. "abstract" means, that you shouldn't /have/ an object of the class. If you have objects from a class, it should almost always have a public destructor.

Comment: Okay, but if I make the destructor public I get a segfault when I try to delete that object

Comment: I am realising that my problem lies somewhere in the class to be deleted. At this point I'm thinking the constructor.

Comment: You have to show some code. The segfault is most likely not from built-in structures but from your own programming :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll mess around a bit and do some googling and maybe ask another question... Shot for the help - must say I did completely miss "abstract".