# Should delegate have a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, delegates

In `delegate` pattern is it good to make the `destuctor` virtual ?

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
};

class MyClassDelegate
{
    ...
};
```

On one hand class `MyClassDelegate` is an interface and supposed to be inherited from, but on the other hand it's not supposed to `delete` the `subclass` via the `MyClassDelegate` pointer

What do you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider making it protected non-virtual - then you're actually enforcing and documenting the fact that you can't delete an object using that kind of pointer. Some more discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353817/should-every-class-have-a-virtual-destructor#answer-353856)

Answer (score 0):

Making destructor virtual if you already have other virtual functions introduces almost no overhead.

Comment: I understand that, but the question is about design, not about performance

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have classes inherit from `MyClassDelegate`, it's best to give it a virtual destructor.

In your initial design, you may not plan to `delete` any pointers to `MyClassDelegate`, but this design will evolve, and your choice will impose a constraint on how this evolves.  This particular constraint is easy to forget, and the crashes (or subtle bugs) that result may take a while to diagnose.