# Factory method creating shared_ptr object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, polymorphism, shared-ptr

When using a factory to create an object, such as in the example below, in certain circumstances the objected wrapped by the `shared_ptr` apparently gets deleted during the return process (during debugging the object is created OK but when it is assigned to `this->xs` an exception is thrown).  When I change the factory method to return a raw pointer, and the `Link::xs` member to be a `unique_ptr` the code runs fine.  What is going on under the hood with `shared_ptr` to cause it to behave this way?  Is it related to the fact that `shared_ptr<CrossSection>` is wrapping a `Circular` object?  Testing has been done using MS Visual C++ 2012.

```
class Link
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<xs::CrossSection> xs;
public:
    void parseXsection(const std::vector<std::string>& parts);
    std::shared_ptr<xs::CrossSection> getXs() { return this->xs; }
};
void Link::parseXsection(const std::vector<std::string>& parts)
{
    this->xs = xs::Factory::create(parts[1]);
}

namespace xs
{
    class CrossSection
    {
    };
    class Circular : public CrossSection
    {
    };
    class Dummy : public CrossSection
    {
    };
    class Factory
    {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<CrossSection> create(const std::string& type);
    };
    std::shared_ptr<CrossSection> Factory::create(const std::string& type)
    {
        if (geom == "circular")
        {
            return std::shared_ptr<CrossSection>(new Circular());
        }
        else
        {
            return std::shared_ptr<CrossSection>(new Dummy());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because `Factory::create` may not return anything when it has to return a `shared_ptr`. You should fix that first.

Comment: I added some more code to fix that problem but in my real implementation that is taken care of.

Comment: I'm sure it was just for the sake of simplicity, but in general it's probably a better idea to use enumerated types and a `switch` statement to do something like that. It is more efficient than doing string comparison, and you have a single place in which you can modify all of your comparison options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, Martin has one option for fixing a destructor problem. You could add a virtual destructor.

However, because you're using `std::shared_ptr`, which employs a bit of type erasure, you could do a smaller fix:

```
std::shared_ptr<CrossSection> Factory::create(const std::string& type)
{
    if (geom == "circular")
        return std::shared_ptr<Circular>(new Circular());
    else
        return std::shared_ptr<Dummy>(new Dummy());
}
```

Or, even better:

```
std::shared_ptr<CrossSection> Factory::create(const std::string& type)
{
    if (geom == "circular")
        return std::make_shared<Circular>();
    else
        return std::make_shared<Dummy>();
}
```

Comment: How would this help any more than having a virtual destructor in `CrossSection`?

Comment: @RSahu: It helps the same amount. You are aware that the `shared_ptr` when constructed for the first time will retain the knowledge of the original pointer's type, and call that destructor. So here, as long as the original shared_ptr constructor has the correct type (which is what my change is all about), then the correct destructor will be called

Comment: No, I didn't know that `shared_ptr` retains the knowledge of the original pointer's type. +1.

Comment: @RSahu [__This post__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913396/why-do-stdshared-ptrvoid-work) has a resonable explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely need to define a virtual destructor in your `CrossSection` base class in order to use polymorphism, i.e. in order to declare derived classes and use them in place of the parent class (so generally almost everytime you want to use derived classes ...)

```
class CrossSection {
  public:
    virtual ~CrossSection() { /* Nothing to do here ... */ }
};
```

See e.g. [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) or [Should every class have a virtual destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353817/should-every-class-have-a-virtual-destructor) for more explanations.

PS: I cannot say right now, if this is the cause for your problems with `shared_ptr`, but it looks a lot like the kind of problems you might encounter if you forget virtual destructors ...