# Memory leak using unique pointer and polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I know that `std::unique_ptr` doesn't guarantee memory safety and especially it is true in the case of circular dependency. However, in my case, I can't see it. `Child` contain `Parent`(or `SecondChild` in case of polymorphism), but neither of them contains `Child`.

Valgrind reports `4 bytes` lost so I suppose that `SecondChild` was not destroyed. My code really relies on polymorphism so I hope to get advice on refactoring that won't change `Parent*` in `Child`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Parent
{
    Parent() {
        cout << "Expr created" << endl;
    }

    ~Parent() {
        cout << "Expr destroyed" << endl;
    }
};

struct Child : public Parent 
{
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> content;
};

struct SecondChild : public Parent 
{
    int val;
};

std::unique_ptr<Parent> foo()
{
    auto test = make_unique<Child>();
    auto content_in_child = make_unique<SecondChild>();
    content_in_child->val = 4;
    test->content = std::move(content_in_child);
    return test;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> high = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Parent` should have a virtual destructor. If a program deletes a pointer to a derived type through a pointer to a base and the destructor of the base isn't virtual the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: note - `shared_ptr` "remembers" the real type and doesn't require a virtual destructor, while `unique_ptr` does need the virtual destructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have undefined behavior, due to the fact that the parent class is missing a virtual destructor, and you are deleting `Child` objects (i.e. `test` from `foo()`) through base class pointers (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<Parent>`).

Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. In your case, it is a memory leak.
[Fix it by adding a `virtual` destructor](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x65Mcc9sj).

```
struct Parent {
     // ....
    virtual ~Parent() {
    //^^^^^^              -----> required !!
    // ...
    }
};
```

---

Read more:

- [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)
- [Should every class have a virtual destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353817/should-every-class-have-a-virtual-destructor)